# Oracle trigger on one-to-many references

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, triggers

I have `two` tables in my oracle db. `Table "B"` has a reference to `table "A"`, so `"A"` might have one or many entries referenced in `"B"`.

Now I have a `trigger` on `"A"` that creates an entry in a history table "`a_hist`" when `"A"` is `updated/deleted/etc`. Is it possible to active the trigger in "A" when a referenced entry in `"B"` has been modified?

I am using hibernate.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a trigger on `B` and within this trigger perform an update on `A` for all rows with referenced values:

```
create trigger b_trg 
after update on B for each row
begin
    update a
     set a.b_id = a.b_id
     where a.b_id = :old.b_id
    ;
end;
```

/